# Why do these slightly different methods for finding roots yield different results?

Tags: math, lisp, scheme, numerical-methods

Consider these two slightly different methods for computing fifth roots:

```
(define (fifth-root-right x)
  (fixed-point-of-transform (lambda (y) (/ x (expt y 4)))
                            (repeated average-damp 2)
                            1.0))

(define (fifth-root-wrong x)
  (fixed-point (repeated 
                (average-damp (lambda (y) (/ x (expt y 4)))) 
                2)
               1.0))
```

Both attempt to compute fifth roots by an average dampened search for a fixed point, since a fifth root of x is a fixed point of the map y -> x/(y^4). I've defined

```
(define (average-damp f)
  (lambda (x) (average x (f x))))
(define tolerance 0.00001)
(define (fixed-point f first-guess)
  (define (close-enough? v1 v2)
    (< (abs (- v1 v2)) tolerance))
  (define (try guess)
    (let ((next (f guess)))
      (if (close-enough? guess next)
          next
          (try next))))
  (try first-guess))
(define (fixed-point-of-transform g transform guess)
  (fixed-point (transform g) guess))
(define (repeated f n)
  (if (= n 1) 
      f
      (compose f (repeated f (- n 1)))))
(define (compose f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

Trying both methods, we get

```
> (fifth-root-right 32)
2.000001512995761
> (fifth-root-wrong 32)
2.8804315666156364
```

Why does the second method give fail to correctly compute fifth roots? Stranger still, if we try this wrong method on fourth or third roots, it works correctly:

```
(define (fourth-root x)
  (fixed-point (repeated 
                (average-damp (lambda (y) (/ x (expt y 3)))) 
                2)
               1.0))

(define (cube-root x)
  (fixed-point (repeated 
                (average-damp (lambda (y) (/ x (expt y 2)))) 
                2)
               1.0))


> (fourth-root 16)
1.982985155172348
> (cube-root 8)
2.0000009087630515
```

For reference, this code attempts to solve [Exercise 1.45](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_thm_1.45) in *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*. Now that I have the right method, my code works, but I don't understand why my wrong method is wrong.

Comment: Your 3rd and 4th degree examples seem to be a copy of the right way, not the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks, fixed labeling of right and wrong now.

Answer (score 3):

The essential difference is in what function is being repeated twice.  In the correct one, `average-damp` is being applied twice, with the net effect of more damping; `((repeated average-damp 2) f)` reduces, mathematically, to `(lambda (x) (+ (* 0.75 x) (* 0.25 (f x))))` (apologies if my syntax is off, my lisp is very, very rusty).  This makes the algorithm less susceptible to the wild fluctuations of the transformation.

The second one, though, applies `(average-damp (lambda (y) (/ x (expt y 2))))` twice - that is, it damps the transformation once and then repeats the resulting function.  One application of `average-damp` is just enough to keep the sequence from diverging but not enough to actually make it converge.  It actually converges to an oscillating state, bouncing back and forth between `1.672645084943273` and `2.8804350135298153`.  However, the damped transformation is applied twice at every step, so `fixed-point`  only sees every other element of the sequence - that subsequence converges to the latter, even though the sequence as a whole fails to converge.

Comment: Also, I suspect the reason it worked for lower orders simply comes down to the fact that less damping was necessary at lower orders, and so the other version which applied less damping was still able to get by.  If you increase the order further you will likely find that still more damping is required to counteract the increased tendency to shoot off to infinity.

Comment: That's correct.  When I did the same problem I found that as n doubles, you need to increase the number of average damps by 1. http://www.billthelizard.com/2010/08/sicp-145-computing-nth-roots.html

Comment: @Bill the Lizard♦: nice post.  I'm pretty sure the reason it works out this way is because this method's step works out to be a really roundabout way of approximating the Newton-Raphson step. Repeating average-damp m times is the same as computing f(y) = (1 - 1/2^m)y + x/(2^m y^(n-1)).  Letting m be log2(n) makes the step function f(y) = (1 - 1/n)y + x/(ny^(n-1)), which is exactly the one Newton-Raphson would use.  Using the floor of that makes it a (good enough) approximation, so I'd say your intuition in the post is spot on.